# Cannot log into localhost during Pixelbook clasp login procedure

Tags: google-apps-script, authentication, localhost, chromebook, clasp

Trying to login to clasp on the Pixelbook. Can't: "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 39133"

Am running the Node server. Can connect to localhost with Node via the command line, but cannot get the clasp login to connect to localhost.

Comment: How did you attempt to log in? What was the actual error? https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/577

Comment: I can get Node to give me a Hello World on localhost port 3000, but I can't get clasp to access localhost.

Comment: The "actual error" appearing on the Chrome page was: "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. Search Google for localhost 39133" That port number changes with every iteration.

Comment: You may need to open an issue on the clasp repo

Comment: Here's my gratuitous reply.  I will do that.  But Google has created a situation in which the user does not know what to do.  I love the Google ecosystem, but I wish they would correct this.

Comment: Okay.  Here's what is going on.  1) you have to go to the clasp repository to understand clasp; the google website is worthless... and this comes from someone who is google's biggest fan 2) clasp has two login options --no-localhost and --creds  3) you login in first with -no-localhost and then when you get your credentials with --creds 4) then you can create a project using sheets quite easily.  Google should correct their website.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer you can write up here. Throw in some relevant GitHub documentation links and some terminal commands and voila, a good self-answer

Comment: Well, what I have said in my previous comment/emendation is true, but it can be elaborated by saying that Chromebooks will not listen to any server except the builtin Apache 2 server on 127.0.0.1:80.  Anything else doesn't work if it is trying to use local host.  So... if you try to run CouchDB for example, you must have it listen on 0.0.0.0 and then Chome can access it. There is a gigantic security issue here I believe which is why Google has restricted it in this way.  For clasp, one simply is unable to use Chrome... which is just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
clasp login --no-localhost
```

That will allow you to login without using the localhost server. You'll just have to do a couple more steps of copy/paste.